# Redirect to one Flask view from another

Tags: python, flask

I have a view that is accessed by clicking a link on the index page.  The view will perform an action and should then show the index page again.  My view does that, but the url is still the url of the action view, not the index view.  How can I redirect back to the index view?

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/u1/')
def u1():
   # do something
   return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.url_for) to build a url to another endpoint in the app.  Use [`redirect`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.redirect) to create a redirect response with that url.

```
from flask import url_for, redirect

@app.route('/u1/')
def u1():
    # do something
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```